# How to extract a single row table data from a pdf using python?

Tags: python, pdf, ocr, python-camelot, tabula-py

I need to extract tabular data from pdfs. Some tables in the pdf comprise of only a single row.
I have been trying to extract the data using camelot library.

Code for extraction using Camelot:

```
pip install camelot-py[cv] tabula-py here
import camelot
file = 'xyz.pdf'
tables = camelot.read_pdf(file,pages ="all")
tables[6].df
```

The above code is not able to extract a single row table info.

For instance, in the pdf: https://www.nirfindia.org/nirfpdfcdn/2022/pdf/Engineering/IR-E-U-0306.pdf,
the tool is not able to detect the last table(under the heading Faculty Details) as it consists of only one row.

Can someone suggest a workaround?

Comment: Can you upload the original pdf?

Comment: Try to reformulate your question according to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can understand from the [docs](https://camelot-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/api.html),
if you want to detect smaller lines, you should increase `line_scale` parameter (default: 15).

In your case, this command works fine:

```
tables = camelot.read_pdf(file, pages ="all", line_scale=80)
```